# PyAudio trying to use JACK

Tags: python, alsa, portaudio, pyaudio, jack

I'm running PyAudio under Python 2.6.6 and would like it to use ALSA and not JACK.

```
In [1]: import pyaudio

In [2]: pa = pyaudio.pa

In [3]: pa.initialize()
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server socket
jack server is not running or cannot be started
```

Comment: What happens if you run JACK manually from a terminal, via `jackstart` ? You may also use http://qjackctl.sourceforge.net/ to control the JACK daemon if you like a graphical user interface better. Anyway, post the daemon's startup output.

Comment: From the docs at [http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/) I think you'll need to pass `pyaudio.paALSA` to `pa.open()` rather than relying on the system to choose.

Comment: Well, I had a similar problem, but the cause was insufficient permissions. On Ubuntu I needed to add myself to the `audio` group. And the error messages were about the same.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088672/pyaudio-working-but-spits-out-error-messages-each-time

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For those who happen to find themselves at this old question via Google:

The message displayed by pyaudio...

```
jack server is not running or cannot be started
```

...is informative, not an error.  It means that portaudio tried and failed to connect to Jack, but doesn't mean that it gave up on everything.

At that point, you should have a fully functional PyAudio object using ALSA.  You can verify this by, e.g., looking at a list of available devices:

```
>>> import pyaudio
>>> pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
[...lots of crap from ALSA...]
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
>>> print '\n'.join([y['name'] 
... for y in [pa.get_device_info_by_index(x)
... for x in range(pa.get_device_count())]])
bcm2835 ALSA: - (hw:0,0)
bcm2835 ALSA: IEC958/HDMI (hw:0,1)
USB Audio Device: - (hw:2,0)
sysdefault
dmix
default
```

Comment: Indeed! And if you want to get rid of the annoying messages, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/36956083.