# Play a sound using python subprocess and threading

Tags: python, multithreading, macos, python-3.x, audio

I am trying to open an alert, then loop a sound until the alert is closed. Then the sound should stop.

I tried this:

```
import threading
import time
import subprocess


stop_sound = False
def play_alarm(file_name = "beep.wav"):
    """Repeat the sound specified to mimic an alarm."""
    while not stop_sound:
        process = subprocess.Popen(["afplay", file_name], shell=False)
        while not stop_sound:
            if process.poll():
                break
            time.sleep(0.1)
        if stop_sound:
            process.kill()

def alert_after_timeout(timeout, message):
    """After timeout seconds, show an alert and play the alarm sound."""
    global stop_sound
    time.sleep(timeout)
    process = None
    thread = threading.Thread(target=play_alarm)
    thread.start()
    # show_alert is synchronous, it blocks until alert is closed
    show_alert(message)

    stop_sound = True
    thread.join()
```

But for some reason the sound doesn't even play.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `process.poll()` returns `0` after the process finishes, which is a falsy value.

Quick fix:

```
while not stop_sound:
    if process.poll() is not None:
        break
```