# PyAudio & WAV understanding how audio is stored and played

Tags: python, numpy, wav, numpy-ndarray, pyaudio

I am having a hard time understanding how these audio files work. I load a WAV file like this:

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
RATE, data = wavfile.read('audio.wav')
```

This is a single channel (MONO) file (I think those are the same thing right?). It has shape `(1555794,)`, and when I play it back it sounds reasonable:

```
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=RATE, input=True, output=True)
stream.write(data)
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

I have another file, which I created in Audacity, which is basically the same thing except I duplicated the first channel to make it two channel. When I load that in, the same way as above, I now have `data_2channel`. When I try to play `data_2channel` back with the same 5 lines as above, it playes but it's twice as slow and sounds like I am playing it as half speed. This isn't unexpected. To get it to play back normally I have to do this:

```
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=RATE, input=True, output=True)
for d in data_2channel:
    stream.write(d)
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

This, I can swallow, but I don't quite understand. Maybe stream recognizing that when I try to write `ndarray`s with 2 values and does something different than if I shove in a 1d array with 13000 values?

So then I thought, well let's convert `data_2channel` back to one channel:

```
>>> data
array([-1552, -1635, -1361, ..., -2695, -3610, -2742], dtype=int16)

>>> data_2channel.T[0]
array([-1551, -1638, -1357, ..., -2700, -3606, -2744], dtype=int16)
```

So `data_2channel.T[0]` looks pretty much the same as `data`, but when I try to play the file I get this error:

```
File "../lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 586, in write
    exception_on_underflow)
ValueError: ndarray is not C-contiguous
```

Not knowing what to think, I tried doing converting `data` to python list and back to an ndarray, and tried playing it back:

```
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=RATE, input=True, output=True)
stream.write(np.array(data.tolist()))
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

It sounds similar to my file; like I slowed it down by 8 times, but still somehow kept the track the same length of time. I don't get why it sounds different. I tried plotting the two arrays and they look exactly the same. But somehow converting it to a list and back again, broke something. Can someone explain to me how this all works?

**EDIT**

Also it's not playing the entire file back to me. It's only playing about 50%. And I found that I can play the two channel file back by changing the `channels` parameter to 2 (duh).

```
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=2, rate=RATE, input=True, output=True)
stream.write(data_2channel)
```

However, the playback on this is cut to about 25% of the original. I'm baffled..

Comment: Are you sure that the file's format is 16 bits per sample? Did you try to play it like [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657103/how-to-play-wav-file-in-python/17657304#17657304)

Comment: Confirmed. When I right click -> show info, the file is "16 bits per sample". It looks like it's playing it the same way that I am, except that that is reading it in differently. I'm using the scipy module, and that example is using the wave module...

Comment: Yes, I know these are two different modules, just wanted to make sure that there's nothing wrong with the file. In second thought, it can be tested with any audio player...

Comment: Can yuo upload your wav files so I'll have a look at them?

Comment: @TDG The audio files are at https://computerengineeringforbabies.com/static/audio.wav and https://computerengineeringforbabies.com/static/audio_2channel.wav I apologize for how unpleasant the files are for playback. Thanks for your help!