# speechRecognition: jack server is not running

Tags: linux, speech-recognition, python-3.4

I'm setting up a sound recognizer with the *speechRecognition* python library.

This is my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer('es-MX')

with sr.Microphone() as mic:
    audio = r.listen(mic)

print(r.recognize(audio))
```

On running I get

```
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:618:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_l$
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
```

I'm using SpeechRecognition version 1.3.1 running on Linux LXLE 14.04 x64 with python 3.4

Answer (score 2):

It tells you it can not record audio on your device. It is not related to a jack server, it also tries to open alsa device and bluetooth audio device. Make sure that audio is properly set on your device. See also

[PyAudio does not work and bricks sound on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182336/pyaudio-does-not-work-and-bricks-sound-on-ubuntu)

[PyAudio working, but spits out error messages each time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088672/pyaudio-working-but-spits-out-error-messages-each-time)

Comment: audio works fine, I can use the mic to speak in skype and everything else is fine

Answer (score 1):

I am having this same error. If you would like a work around you can use my code I wrote. I used the sounddevice library to record audio while there is audio it saves into one file, then convert it to text using the speech recognition library. The error comes when microphone is called in as it is using PyAudio.

https://shepai.github.io/code/PetSHEP/soundLib.py

The following lines should replace your "with microphone" bit

with sr.AudioFile(filename) as source:
Audio=r.record(source)

This is how I got round the problem, hope it helps :)