# Python sound synthesis, what is the problem here?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, audio, pyaudio

I'm trying to play a sinewave using python pyaudio, here's the code that I found on the same website.

```
 import pyaudio
 import numpy as np

 p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

volume = 0.5     # range [0.0, 1.0]
fs = 44100       # sampling rate, Hz, must be integer
duration = 1.0   # in seconds, may be float
f = 440.0        # sine frequency, Hz, may be float

# generate samples, note conversion to float32 array
samples = (np.sin(2*np.pi*np.arange(fs*duration)*f/fs)).astype(np.float32)

# for paFloat32 sample values must be in range [-1.0, 1.0]
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                channels=1,
                rate=fs,
                output=True)

# play. May repeat with different volume values (if done interactively) 
stream.write(volume*samples)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

p.terminate()
```

I'm getting the error,

```
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:600:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1035:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:600:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1035:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1035:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
```

What seems to be the issue here? How to fix it?
I'm on Arch Linux if that helps.

Comment: Do these [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31642765/speechrecognition-jack-server-is-not-running) work for you?