# PyAudio prints ALSA warnings and does not work

Tags: linux, python-3.x, speech-to-text, alsa

I am trying to run a basic python speech to text code. This is the code.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:                
audio = r.listen(source)                   

try:
   print("You said " + r.recognize(audio))     
except LookupError:                            
   print("Could not understand audio")
```

The code works fine until it reaches the print stage, then it throws this error. Is there anything that I have done wrong?

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
```

Comment: These are not error messages.

Comment: i couldnt make anything out of it so i thought it was an error message and sorry i dint know that since i am very new to them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyAudio working, but spits out error messages each time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088672/pyaudio-working-but-spits-out-error-messages-each-time)

Comment: Thanks man that worked like a charm even though I'm unable to remove the last 4 lines

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182336/pyaudio-does-not-work-and-bricks-sound-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 11):

if someone is still looking for getting rid of

```
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
```

I just commented out all pcm.surround* lines in "PCM interface" section in

```
/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf
```

file and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have multiple audio input sources, and the first one is not supported by the `speech-recognition` library. There is another possibility that you have no audio inputs at all.

Try different indexes (e.g. 0, 1, 2, etc) with `sr.Microphone(...)` as per example below:

```
with sr.Microphone(device_index=0) as source:
```

But first, it's a good idea to run `cat /proc/asound/card` to see what audio devices you've got.

Comment: the "cat /proc/asound/card" returns as no such directory found

Comment: "OSError: [Errno -9998] Invalid number of channels" if i give the device index as more than 0, and returns the same statements as above when I give the device_index value as 0

Comment: Sorry, that must be `cat /proc/asound/cards`. Have no Linux at this moment. Have a look at this article: http://alsa.opensrc.org/Proc_asound_documentation

Comment: Just realized that you would like to get rid off error messages. See this post for your problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/13453192/1786034

Comment: Hmmm it works for the pcm.c errors but i cant remove the other four lines(last 4).

Comment: I recommend you to read this: https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/issues/27