# Errors while running speech_recognition module

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition, pyaudio, pyttsx3

I'm working on a project which uses the speech_recognition module.

```
    # Importing all the installed packages
    import speech_recognition as sr
    audio = sr.Recognizer
    try:
     
     with sr.Microphone() as source:
    voice = audio.listen(source)
    command = audio.recognize_google(voice)
    print(command)
  finally:
pass
```

I'm getting this error

I tried all the possible solutions and yet I get the same error again and again
I'm using the PyCharm editor.

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:877:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:877:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:877:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:877:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWitePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/rohan/Rocland_Python/Rocland/Rocland2.py", line 9, in <module>
command = audio.recognize_google(sound)
File "/home/rohan/Rocland_Python/Rocland/venv/lib/python3.9/site- 
 packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 858, in recognize_google
 if not isinstance(actual_result, dict) or len(actual_result.get("alternative", [])) == 0: 
raise UnknownValueError()
speech_recognition.UnknownValueError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/rohan/Rocland_Python/Rocland/Rocland2.py", line 10, in <module>
except:   command = command.lower()
NameError: name 'command' is not defined
```

**Please help me. Thanks!**

Comment: This  is probably the  underlying problem:    
      Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started

Comment: Look  here for some details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182336/pyaudio-does-not-work-and-breaks-sound-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i have the speech recognition code snippet which i have used in one of my code , i hope it will work for yours also:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

rObject = sr.Recognizer() 
audio = '' 
with sr.Microphone() as source: 
    print("Speak...")   
    audio = rObject.listen(source, phrase_time_limit = 0) 
    print("Stop.")
    try: 
        text = rObject.recognize_google(audio, language ='en-US') 
        print("You : "+ text)  
    except: 
        speak("Could not understand your audio...PLease try again !")
```

Try and checkout !

There is socket as well as `command = command.lower()`

Comment: This is only tangentially related to the question

Comment: According to question I have given this code snippet.

Comment: @DavidW My given code has worked properly see it once .

Comment: OK but all you've done is copied a tutorial from the internet (complete with a distinctive typo). There's no guidance as to why your code works and the original code doesn't so there's nothing to learn from it. I don't see how this is a useful answer. And I also don't see how it's useful to do the same thing on 4 other questions.

Comment: Then how it approved sir ? and  i have used to make Jarvis and this is proper code .

Comment: I think a more useful answer would have also helped the asker understand what they did wrong.

Comment: Ok next time i will remember @DavidW