# Fluid-synth always ensure that the bank-number is present

Tags: artificial-intelligence, midi, midi-instrument, fluidsynth

**Problem Summarization:**

I am currently analyzing instrument/note pair using pretty_midi and fluidsynth in python. Sometimes when I call fluidsynth on my instrument object, I get an error like:

`fluidsynth: error: There is no preset with bank number x and preset number z in SoundFont 1`

---

**Searched:**

From what I understand the problem seems to be that I need a sound font file. Which I also found from someone else with a similar question here:

[Running pyfluidsynth + pyaudio demo, many problems with alsa and jack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023545/running-pyfluidsynth-pyaudio-demo-many-problems-with-alsa-and-jack)

Sadly it is unanswered...

---

**What I would like from this post...(please and thank you):**

1. I would like to know how to download multiple song fonts/how they are stored.
2. When the error does occur how do I better interrupt the error so I can look for the song font file online or see if I already on my local machine.
3. Why am I still getting output from fluidsynth if it is throwing an error??? Again I am doing analyzing instrument/note pairs by comparing synthesized waveforms will this affect anything I am doing?

---

**Code Pictures: (Using pictures because the problem is more of a backend problem/I have a lot of other code that makes the cogs of this work properly.)**

*How I am processing output:*
[image]

---

*Extracting attributes of instrument note pair. To make fluidsynth work with a different font file I would pass it through as a parameter inside fluidsynth.*
[image]

---

*Overall Ouput:*

### [image]

> I would like to say thank you in advance to all for even looking this over. The overall community has been very helpful in the last few post so again thank you to all.

Comment: Three questions in one is too broad for one question. Anyway, when fluidsynth does not find a preset, it falls back to a default, which might or might not be appropriate.

Comment: Alright, I will remember that for the future posts. Ok, so how do I find the proper presents when these errors occur.

Comment: What do you mean with "proper"? Usually, banks are organized that you can fall back to bank 0 to get a similar instrument.

Comment: I mean how do I get the most appropriate?

Comment: Ok, I can work with similar instruments I think. I am currently just trying to turn off the warning that is being thrown now of "fluidsynth error: There is no present with..."