# Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear (pyaudio)

Tags: python-3.x, pyaudio

The question is related to this [pydub-Issue](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/issues/110#issuecomment-124205306). They told me the error message is related to pyaudio.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pydub, pydub.playback

wav = pydub.AudioSegment.from_wav('/home/user/complete.wav')
pydub.playback.play(wav)
```

This code raise that errors I don't understand.

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
```

The wav itself is played well. How can I prevent that errors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Refused connections are removed when removing the following bluetooth package (if you really want to) `sudo apt-get remove bluez-alsa`

Unknown PCM cards are removed by commenting out relevant lines in `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf`.

The others I don't know about, but you could start looking here: [PyAudio working, but spits out error messages each time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088672/pyaudio-working-but-spits-out-error-messages-each-time).