# Linux: Portaudio and ALSA error messages when calling audio (in Python)

Tags: python, linux, alsa, portaudio

I have this Python script which I coded a couple of months ago (it worked fine back then, so my problem isn't a code related one), but it doesn't work on the system I needed to set up last week.
I get the following error for all Python scripts calling audio (I guess it is not related to Python though):

```
portaudio error in Pa_OpenStream: Invalid number of channels

Portaudio error: Invalid number of channelsportaudio error in 
Pa_AbortStream: Invalid stream pointer

portaudio error in Pa_CloseStream: Invalid stream pointer


Server not booted.

ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear

ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown cards.pcm.center_lfe

ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side

ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map

ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map

ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map

ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map

Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory

Cannot connect to server request channel

jack server is not running or cannot be started

JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for 4294967295, skipping unlock

JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for 4294967295, skipping unlock

Expression 'parameters->channelCount <= maxChans' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1514

Expression 'ValidateParameters( inputParameters, hostApi, StreamDirection_In )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2818

The Server must be booted!
```

Please help me to fix my libs or whatever needs to be done. Thank you very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyAudio working, but spits out error messages each time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088672/pyaudio-working-but-spits-out-error-messages-each-time)

Comment: Unfortunately not, the script wont start and the error message keeps repeating until I terminate the script.

Comment: The linked answer tells you that the error messages are useless. Check if `aplay` etc. works. And the problem might be with your script, which you have kept secret.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, at least I was able to narrow down the cause of my problem to a python lib I was using to run the audio in my script because it worked with aplay and Pygame. I'm sorry for posting my problem in a wrong way. Thanks again!