# How do i make the Microphone() function work in SpeechRecognition in Linux

Tags: linux, python-3.x, speech-recognition, microphone

I am trying SpeechRecognition module but i can get it to work.
Can anyone pleas help me.

I am using Linux Mint

Thias is my python code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
try:
    with sr.Microphone() as source:                
    audio = r.listen(source)
    text = r.recognize_google(audio)
    print(text)
except:
    print("not working")
```

and I get this error:

```
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:618:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open 
slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1052:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
 ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM 
cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM 
cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM 
cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1052:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, 
skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, 
skipping unlock
Expression 'parameters->channelCount <= maxChans' failed in 
'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1514
Expression 'ValidateParameters( inputParameters, hostApi, 
StreamDirection_In )' failed in 
'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', 
line: 2818
not working
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyAudio working, but spits out error messages each time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088672/pyaudio-working-but-spits-out-error-messages-each-time)