# PyAudio throws ´unable to open slave` error

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyaudio

Hi every time i execute pyauido.PyAudio() i get the following error.
I try to display the audio recorded by my mic using these instructions: https://swharden.com/wp/2016-07-19-realtime-audio-visualization-in-python/
and use my USB-Mic and the headphone-jack of my raspberry pi 3+

```
Expression 'alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near( pcm, hwParams, &alsaPer                                  iodFrames, &dir )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 924
Expression 'alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near( pcm, hwParams, &alsaPer                                   iodFrames, &dir )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 924
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Expression 'alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near( pcm, hwParams, &alsaPer                                   iodFrames, &dir )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 924
```

Update: As mentioned in the comments i got rid of the "Unknown PCM" by editing the alsa.conf file, but i realised that the traceback was not added to the snippet i posted here so here is the "new, complete"-Message:

```
Expression 'alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near( pcm, hwParams, &alsaPeriodFrames, &dir )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 924
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:638:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Expression 'alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near( pcm, hwParams, &alsaPeriodFrames, &dir )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 924
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sound.py", line 9, in <module>
    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 750, in open
    stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 441, in __init__
    self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
IOError: [Errno -9996] Invalid input device (no default output device)
```

Additional information:

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 2: Device [USB PnP Audio Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

```
[12:06:02] openhabian@openhab:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: b1 [bcm2835 HDMI 1], device 0: bcm2835 HDMI 1 [bcm2835 HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 4/4
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
card 1: Headphones [bcm2835 Headphones], device 0: bcm2835 Headphones [bcm2835 Headphones]
  Subdevices: 4/4
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
```

.asoundrc - configuration:

```
pcm.!default {
  type asym
  capture.pcm "hw:2,0"
  playback.pcm "hw:1,0"
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code that created the error?

Comment: The easiest way to recreate the error is to open python, import pyaudio and try to execute the PyAudio()-Method ```python
Python 2.7.16 (default, Oct 10 2019, 22:02:15)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyaudio
>>> p = pyaudio.PyAudio()```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the code. Comments are not suitable for code fragments.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else comes along this problem here at least a solution for removing the "Unknown..."-Messages:

[PyAudio working, but spits out error messages each time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088672/pyaudio-working-but-spits-out-error-messages-each-time)