# How do I get rid of error:jack server is not running or cannot be started

Tags: python, operating-system, speech-recognition, pyaudio, gtts

I am using gtts pyaudio and speechRecognition to create a siri-like chatbot on my raspberry pi.
It is all working fine however it also produces this error

```
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
```

Do you know What it is if it is harmless and how I can get rid of it?

Thank you for you time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyAudio working, but spits out error messages each time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088672/pyaudio-working-but-spits-out-error-messages-each-time)

Comment: Those messages are harmless, you might rebuild portaudio to get rid of them though.

Comment: Have you found any solution? I'm in same situation. Just a clean Raspbian flash, just apt install kodi and don't do anything...