# PyAudio warnings poluting output

Tags: io-redirection, suppress-warnings, pyaudio

I have this program that listens to the microphone and tries to recognize what was said:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import speech_recognition

recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()

class Recognition:

    def __init__(self):
        self.recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()

    def listen(self):
        with speech_recognition.Microphone() as source:
            self.recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
            self.audio = self.recognizer.listen(source)

    def recognize_sphinx(self):
        decoder = self.recognizer.recognize_sphinx(self.audio, show_all=True)
        for best, i in zip(decoder.nbest(), range(10)):
            return best.hypstr


r = Recognition()
r.listen()
print(r.recognize_sphinx())
```

Although the code works, it does display the following warnings along with the output:

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for 4294967295, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for 4294967295, skipping unlock
potato
```

The problem is I want a script to execute the code above and read its output (potato), but the returned result is mixed with all those errors. I tried the solution I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13453192/520830), but it only suppress the alsa warnings. Probably messing with alsa/pulseaudio configs will solve this problem, but I don't want to do that on every machine that runs the code.

I also tried redirecting stdin/stderr to null, but didn't suppress anything.

I have a workaround in mind that is, when the script runs this program, to get only the last line, but I want that only as a last resource.

Comment: Just to point you out, that this problem is due to `alsa.conf` file having crappy settings such as `pcm.rear cards.pcm.rear`. Removing those from `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf` should solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning/status messages go to the standard error output (`stderr`), while the output of your `print()` call goes to the standard output (`stdout`).
It should be trivial to separate the two.

If you want to actually suppress the warning/status messages, you can have a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36116369/500098) to the SO-question you were mentioning, or [the more verbose answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36966379) I've linked to from there.

Comment: I'm aware stderr is not mixed with stdout, but when I ran the code externally, the errors came along with the desired output, as I stated in my answer. So yes, unless there's another solution, I need to suppress the warnings to have a code without workarounds. I'll try the module you mentioned as soon as I can. Thanks!

Comment: How did you run your script and how did you try to grab `stdout`?

Comment: I run it in emacs with the command `shell-command-to-string`. Now that you mentioned, maybe that's the problem. Anyway, I was able to solve this and get a better behavior using emacsclient. Thanks for the help. Cheers!

Comment: It would be nice if pyaudio used logging for messages.