# Getting unwanted output in terminal with speech_recognition in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I wrote this code using a library called "speech_recognition" wherein it uses the microphone to get what user speaks and print it out into the terminal.
This is what the code is:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import webbrowser as wb

r1 = sr.Recognizer()
r2 = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print('Give command')
    audio = r1.listen(source)
    command = r2.recognize_google(audio)
    print (command)
```

I would expect this to firstly `print('Give command')` followed by it listening to audio and printing out what it heard.
It does do that but this is the entire output I get when I say - "hello please help":

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:869:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:869:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:869:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:869:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
Give command
hello please help
```

The last 2 lines of the output are the only things I want to see.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyAudio warnings poluting output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37733318/pyaudio-warnings-poluting-output)

Comment: No, I followed the steps but it still gives the same output as before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using speech_recog. library for something like a speech assistant, it would be better to not use the terminal to show o/p at all. Instead, make the output in speech. This makes the app better and gets rid of all of these garbage warnings