# Generating audio on Raspberry Pi using PyAudio, results in audio with stutter

Tags: python, audio, raspberry-pi3, alsa, pyaudio

I need to use python to generate sound on my raspberry pi, I just need to generate a sine wave of specific frequencies. I have attempted to do this using PyAudio and the following code (which I found here https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2012-September/091476.html)

```
import math
import struct
import pyaudio

def play_tone(frequency, amplitude, duration, fs, stream):
    N = int(fs / frequency)
    T = int(frequency * duration)  # repeat for T cycles
    dt = 1.0 / fs
    # 1 cycle
    tone = (amplitude * math.sin(2 * math.pi * frequency * n * dt)
            for n in xrange(N))
    # todo: get the format from the stream; this assumes Float32
    data = ''.join(struct.pack('f', samp) for samp in tone)
    for n in xrange(T):
        stream.write(data)

fs = 48000
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(
    format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
    channels=1,
    rate=fs,
    output=True)

# play the C major scale
scale = [130.8, 146.8, 164.8, 174.6, 195.0, 220.0, 246.9, 261.6]
for tone in scale:
    play_tone(tone, 0.5, 0.75, fs, stream)

# up an octave
for tone in scale[1:]:
    play_tone(2*tone, 0.5, 0.75, fs, stream)

stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

This works perfectly fine on my computer but not on the Raspberry Pi. When I run the code on the Raspberry Pi the sound is very stuttery and I get the following errors:

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.front
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround21
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround21
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround40
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround41
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround50
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround51
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround71
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
```

I've already spent a long time trying to fix this problem with the information that I've found on the internet but to no avail.

Unfortunately I'm very new to this and don't really know what I'm doing so I'm sorry if this post is too unspecific, I'll do my best to clarify anything necessary.

Comment: These messages are harmless. What is the CPU utilization while your code is running?

Comment: Regarding the harmless but annoying messages, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/36956083/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/7088672/. Other than that, did you try to change the block size or the latency settings?

Comment: @Matthias How do i change the block size and latency settings? And to what should I change them? Sorry - total beginner here

Comment: I don't know, I'm not a PyAudio user. I'm a user of the [sounddevice](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/) module (and its author, too), you can have a look at the documentation there (especially at the example programs!) and if you have further questions, don't hesitate to ask here.